# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/myfaces/custom/fileupload/UploadedFile

Tags: maven, jsf, jpa, file-upload, tomahawk

I want to upload files and show them in jsf page, for that I'm using tomahawk 1.1.12, jsf 2.0 and jpa 2, I'm following The BalusC tutorial but the project connot deploy and gives the error :  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/myfaces/custom/fileupload/UploadedFile
pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>maven.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>mavenTest</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>oss.sonatype.org</id>
            <name>OSS Sonatype Staging</name>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/staging</url>
         </repository>
         <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
         </repository>
          <repository>
              <id>central</id>
              <name>Central Repository</name>
              <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
              <layout>default</layout>
              <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
              </snapshots>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>apache-maven-snapshots</id>
                <url>
                http://people.apache.org/repo/m2-snapshot-repository
                </url>
                <releases>
                  <enabled>false</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                  <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>myfaces-staging</id>
                <url>
                     http://people.apache.org/builds/myfaces/m2-staging-repository
                </url>
                <releases>
                   <enabled>false</enabled>
                <!--
                Enable to test a MyFaces core release candidate with tomahawk
                -->
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
     </repositories>

 <dependencies>
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0-RC1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commonj.sdo</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.11</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.11</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomahawk</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.12</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
         </dependency>
       <!--   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomahawk</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.14</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>-->       
     </dependencies>
</project>
```

my managed bean :

```
package mbeans;

//import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
//import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;

/*
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
//import org.apache.commons.el.Logger;
//import org.apache.log4j.*;
//import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggerFactory;
*/
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.myfaces.custom.fileupload.UploadedFile;

import daoImpl.DocDAO;
import entities.Document;

//import org.slf4j.*;


@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class DocBean {
    public DocDAO docDAO;
    private Part file;
    private  String titreDocument;
    private  String descriptionDocument;
    private  String lien;
    private  String dateMise;
    private String Categorie;
    private Integer sizeDocument;
    private String sousCategorie;

    public DocBean(){
        docDAO=new DocDAO();
    }

    private UploadedFile uploadedFile;
    private String fileName;

    // Actions ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public void submit() {

        // Just to demonstrate what information you can get from the uploaded file.
        System.out.println("File type: " + uploadedFile.getContentType());
        System.out.println("File name: " + uploadedFile.getName());
        System.out.println("File size: " + uploadedFile.getSize() + " bytes");

        // Prepare filename prefix and suffix for an unique filename in upload folder.
        String prefix = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(uploadedFile.getName());
        String suffix = FilenameUtils.getExtension(uploadedFile.getName());

        // Prepare file and outputstream.
        File file = null;
        OutputStream output = null;

        try {
            // Create file with unique name in upload folder and write to it.
            file = File.createTempFile(prefix + "_", "." + suffix, new File("c:/data"));
            output = new FileOutputStream(file);
            IOUtils.copy(uploadedFile.getInputStream(), output);
            fileName = file.getName();

            // Show succes message.
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("uploadForm", new FacesMessage(
                FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "File upload succeed!", null));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Cleanup.
            if (file != null) file.delete();

            // Show error message.
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("uploadForm", new FacesMessage(
                FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "File upload failed with I/O error.", null));

            // Always log stacktraces (with a real logger).
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(output);
        }
    }

    // Getters ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public UploadedFile getUploadedFile() {
        return uploadedFile;
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    // Setters ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public void setUploadedFile(UploadedFile uploadedFile) {
        this.uploadedFile = uploadedFile;
    }

    //@EJB
    //private DocDAO fileUploaderEJB;

    //private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DocDAO.class);

    //public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
       /* titreDocument = event.getFile().getFileName();
        //String contentType = event.getFile().getContentType();
        byte[] bytes = event.getFile().getContents();

        Document garbage = new Document();
        garbage.setDescriptionDocument(titreDocument);
        garbage.setFile(bytes);
        garbage.setDescriptionDocument("info about the file");
        fileUploaderEJB.uploadGarbage(garbage);

        //((Log) logger).info("Uploaded: {}");

        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Succesful", event.getFile()
                .getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);*/
    //}
public String upload() throws IOException{
    file.write("C:\\data\\"+getFilename(file));

        return"succes";
    }
    private static String getFilename(Part part){
        for(String cd: part.getHeader("content-disposition").split(";")){
            if(cd.trim().startsWith("filename")){
                String filename=cd.substring(cd.indexOf('=') + 1).trim().replace("\"", "");
                return filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('/') + 1).substring(filename.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
            }

        }
        return null;
    }
    /*public List<Document> getAlldoc(){
        return docDAO.getAllDoc();
    }
    public String createdoc(){
        docDAO.createDoc(titreDocument, descriptionDocument, sousCategorie, Categorie, sizeDocument, dateMise, lien);;
        sizeDocument=null;
        titreDocument="";
        descriptionDocument="";
        lien="";
        sousCategorie="";
        dateMise="";
        Categorie="";
        return "success";
    }*/


    public String getSousCategorie() {
        return sousCategorie;
    }

    public void setSousCategorie(String sousCategorie) {
        this.sousCategorie = sousCategorie;
    }

    public String getTitreDocument() {
        return titreDocument;
    }

    public void setTitreDocument(String titreDocument) {
        this.titreDocument = titreDocument;
    }

    public String getDescriptionDocument() {
        return descriptionDocument;
    }

    public void setDescriptionDocument(String descriptionDocument) {
        this.descriptionDocument = descriptionDocument;
    }

    public String getDateMise() {
        return dateMise;
    }

    public void setDateMise(String dateMise) {
        this.dateMise = dateMise;
    }

    public String getCategorie() {
        return Categorie;
    }

    public void setCategorie(String categorie) {
        Categorie = categorie;
    }

    public Integer getSizeDocument() {
        return sizeDocument;
    }

    public void setSizeDocument(Integer sizeDocument) {
        this.sizeDocument = sizeDocument;
    }

    public String getLien() {
        return lien;
    }
    public void setLien(String lien) {
        this.lien = lien;
    }


    public Part getFile() {
        return file;
    }
    public void setFile(Part file) {
        this.file = file;
    }
}
```

my entity :

```
package entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;


/**
 * The persistent class for the document database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="document")
@NamedQuery(name="Document.findAll", query="SELECT d FROM Document d")
public class Document  {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="\"idDocument\"", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private Integer idDocument;

    @Column(length=45)
    private String categorie;

    @Column(name="\"dateMise\"", length=45)
    private String dateMise;

    @Column(name="\"descriptionDocument\"", length=60)
    private String descriptionDocument;

    @Lob
    @Column
    private byte[] file;

    @Column(length=45)
    private String lien;

    @Column(name="\"sizeDocument\"")
    private Integer sizeDocument;

    @Column(name="\"sousCategorie\"", length=45)
    private String sousCategorie;

    @Column(name="\"titreDocument\"", length=45)
    private String titreDocument;

    public Document() {
    }

    public Integer getIdDocument() {
        return this.idDocument;
    }

    public void setIdDocument(Integer idDocument) {
        this.idDocument = idDocument;
    }

    public String getCategorie() {
        return this.categorie;
    }

    public void setCategorie(String categorie) {
        this.categorie = categorie;
    }

    public String getDateMise() {
        return this.dateMise;
    }

    public void setDateMise(String dateMise) {
        this.dateMise = dateMise;
    }

    public String getDescriptionDocument() {
        return this.descriptionDocument;
    }

    public void setDescriptionDocument(String descriptionDocument) {
        this.descriptionDocument = descriptionDocument;
    }

    public byte[] getFile() {
        return this.file;
    }

    public void setFile(byte[] file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public String getLien() {
        return this.lien;
    }

    public void setLien(String lien) {
        this.lien = lien;
    }

    public Integer getSizeDocument() {
        return this.sizeDocument;
    }

    public void setSizeDocument(Integer sizeDocument) {
        this.sizeDocument = sizeDocument;
    }

    public String getSousCategorie() {
        return this.sousCategorie;
    }

    public void setSousCategorie(String sousCategorie) {
        this.sousCategorie = sousCategorie;
    }

    public String getTitreDocument() {
        return this.titreDocument;
    }

    public void setTitreDocument(String titreDocument) {
        this.titreDocument = titreDocument;
    }

}
```

and my web page xhtml:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="3">
                    <h:outputLabel for="file" value="Select file" />
                    <t:inputFileUpload id="file" value="#{docBean.uploadedFile}" required="true" />
                    <h:message for="file" style="color: red;" />

                    <h:panelGroup />
                    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{docBean.submit}" />
                    <h:message for="uploadForm" infoStyle="color: green;" errorStyle="color: red;" />
                </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
    <h:outputLink value="file/#{docBean.fileName}" rendered="#{docBean.fileName != null}">
                Download back
            </h:outputLink>
```

any idea ?

Comment: Have you ensured the correspondant jars available in the lib project folder ?

Comment: Thanks Omar, I'm using maven and when I check maven dependecies I found the class  Lorg/apache/myfaces/custom/fileupload/UploadedFile but the error says : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/myfaces/custom/fileupload/UploadedFile.

Comment: Did you use to re-clean & re-build the project ?

Comment: yes I re-clean and redploy but can't deploy because of the error mentionned above.

Comment: But did you check anyway wether that class(jar) is included in the lib folder ?

Comment: yes they are included in maven dependencies

Comment: maven dependencies/                                                   /tomahawk20.jar                                                              /org.apache.myfaces.custom.fileupload.UploadFile

Comment: I hope it's not a version issue. Maybe you try to downlaod another (stable) one.

Comment: This question has answers that cover all that you need to know
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java

Comment: I tried to change versions in pom.xml so starting from tomahaw20 v1.1.10 to tomahawk 1.1.14 and the problem sitll here, I don't know what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks Omar it was a matter of version I tried to upload using only jsf 2.2 with no tomahawk or primefaces.
resolved

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomahawk</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.12</version>
</dependency>
```

replace with

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomahawk20</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply , I do what you are proposing Michele Mariotti but the project still not deploying and still giving me the error